# Azure DevOps multi CI/CD

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a following use case:

We have one solution that contains 5-10 different services (.NET Framework Web Apps of various versions) within. We have to setup CI/CD in Azure DevOps to be able to automate the deployments of each services separately (or all services at once). There will be around 5 different environments for each service.

**Challenges:**

- We are trying to avoid having (# of services X # of environments) seperate builds and releases (~50 build/ ~50 release).
- We do have to be able to deploy one service alone without others being affected.
- We do have to be able to deploy ALL services all at once for mass deployments.

P.S. We are currently using trunk based development but I am thinking about moving to giflow to have branch based triggers as I feel it would be easier to manage in this case.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts&tabs=schema This is currently where my eyes are on. Create a YAML for each service and dynamically spin up build/release, deploy and destroy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CI** - handled by your build server (e.g. teamcity). Responsibility: Build, Test, Obfuscate, Create Packages and lastly push Packages to nuget server (.net specific).  Traditionally besides the app code you also need at least 2 other packages: db migrations, infra migrations.

You build packages once and deploy the exact version everywhere else you want it to go.
https://gist.github.com/leblancmeneses/1d352bb79447cd7a486598c4dc796ef1
This script works in conjunction with https://github.com/leblancmeneses/RobustHaven.DevOps

**CD** - handled by something like octopus deploy. Responsibly: orchestrate deployment process across your cluster. Octopus pulls packages from nuget server and moves them to what ever environment you want and to whatever machines encompasses that environment.

https://www.robusthaven.com/presentations/DevOps

Answer (score 0):

you dont really need 50 builds, you can use a single build per service (assuming builds for different environments are identical) and build from different branches. technically you can get away with a single release for 50 environments if you create your triggers\phases properly, but that would be a mess, just create a single one for each environment. I cant see how managing 50 environments on a single release is manageable.

when yaml release pipelines arrive, this becomes trivial, right now its not, unfortunatelly.

Comment: How would I override variables in a build configuration depending on the branch triggering the build?  Also, are you aware if azure DevOps allows to have multiple YAML configuration inside of one solution/repo? (One build yaml for each service/project)

Comment: yes, it allows you to use different yaml files for a single solution, you just have to use visual build wizard to configure yaml builds. I dont think you can scope variables to branches, so that means you'd have to use different builds. with releases you can scope variables to environments